# Is the Rabin fingerprinting scheme with a random polynomial a universal hash function family?

Tags: hashing

Say I have a greater-than-expected number of collisions in my hash table that has 2^w buckets (half of them empty).
So I pick a fresh new random CRC polynomial that generates w-bit check values
(i.e., a w+1 bit value with the high bit and the low bit forced to 1, and the other w-1 bits pulled from /dev/random ),
and re-hash all the items in my table using the new CRC as a hash function.
Will most such hash functions have close to the expected number of collisions predicted by the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem),
no matter what particular strings Mallory gave me to use as keys for the items in my hash table?

In other words:

Is the [Rabin fingerprinting scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint) with a random polynomial a [universal hash function family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/universal_hashing)?

Comment: Is Theoretical Computer Science http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ a better place for questions like this?